# How to place a div at the start of every "new" page

Tags: html, css

I have been having trouble thinking of how to ask this question and I thinks that's why I couldn't find anything on Google! I am trying to put a div at the top of every page of my website. So to start you would see the first div then as you scroll down the next div would come into view but if the div was exactly at the top of the page then the following one would not be in view yet. How would I implement this for varying screen sizes.

I have the second one working. So you would see the main page, then start scrolling to see the next div. I did this using:

```
.first-header {
    height: 150px;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #003366;
    bottom: -150px;
}
```

but I can't figure out how to do an indefinite amount of them. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Chris